# How do I get a list of unique sender-email addresses (and the count) for a given Exchange mailbox

Tags: email, scripting, powershell, exchange-server, whitelist

I am planning on creating a whitelist for a given mailbox in our Exchange server. To create the whitelist I want the following info about this mailbox:

1. A list of all unique senders (and the mail-count) in descending order
2. A list of all unique domains (and the mail-count) in descending order

Is something like this possible perhaps via Powershell, or do I need to write a program to iterate over all mails and collect this in another program?

Answer (score 0):

You can get that information from the message tracking logs, within the timespan that you have logs retained, using Powershell and the Exchange Management cmdlet get-messagetrackinglog.

To get it from the current contents of the mailbox, you can use Powershell and the Exchange Web Services Managed API.  MessageOps offers a free module you may want to look into that can help simplify the coding.

Getting it from the message tracking logs will be considerably less coding but may not be as comprehensive as using the mailbox contents.